# MYSQL stored procedure select statement select incorrect ID

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, select

I am not the most knowledge able person when it comes to stored procedures, and this problem is blowing my mind!

Basically I am just trying to run a simple update statement, but the user's ID that I am selecting to update the row is not correct when I run it in the procedure, but if I run the same select statement outside the procedure it returns the expected results.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE catchUpBbs_Users()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE deleteUser, keepUser VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE id INT;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT u.username, b.username, b.id from users u RIGHT     JOIN bbs_users b ON u.username = b.username WHERE u.username IS NULL;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;     
    OPEN cur1;
        allusers: LOOP 
            FETCH cur1 INTO keepUser, deleteUser, id;
            IF done THEN 
                LEAVE allusers; 
            END IF;
IF deleteUser != 'anonymous' THEN 

-- This is where the problems start

-- Just for test purposes, returns correct id and username 
SELECT id, username FROM bbs_users WHERE username = deleteUser; 

-- Just for test purposes, return INCORRECT id, but the CORRECT username  
SELECT id, username FROM bbs_users WHERE username = 'anonymous'; 

-- The update statement that does not work as I want it to, sets the user_id to be what it already it, so no updates occur
UPDATE bbs_posts SET user_id = (SELECT id FROM bbs_users WHERE username = 'anonymous') WHERE user_id = (SELECT id FROM bbs_users WHERE username = deleteUser);

-- delete the user from the bbs_users table
DELETE FROM bbs_users WHERE username = deleteUser;

END IF;
    END LOOP allusers;
    CLOSE cur1;
END;

$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I call the procedure the two test select statements return:

1) These results are both correct

```
 SELECT id, username FROM bbs_users WHERE username = deleteUser;
 +------+----------+
 | id   | username |
 +------+----------+
 |   13 | deleteme |
 +------+----------+
```

2) The ID is incorrect, but the username is incorrect, the ID should be 1

```
 SELECT id, username FROM bbs_users WHERE username = 'anonymous'; 
 +------+-----------+
 | id   | username  |
 +------+-----------+
 |   13 | anonymous |
 +------+-----------+
```

When I run the same, minus the variable, select statements outside the procedure both return the correct results

1) These results are both correct

```
SELECT id, username FROM bbs_users WHERE username = 'deleteme';
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
| 13 | deleteme |
+----+----------+
```

2) These results are both correct

```
SELECT id, username FROM bbs_users WHERE username = 'anonymous';
+----+-----------+
| id | username  |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | anonymous |
+----+-----------+
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there something that I missed when it comes to selects and variables when using a stored procedure?

Any help or advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have a scalar variable called `id` defined in your cursor and you are selecting into it, so both of your select statements inside of the cursor are using that stored scalar value for all references to `id`.

In order to get the "correct" value, you'll need to remove all ambiguity:

```
-- Just for test purposes, returns correct id and username 
SELECT b.id, b.username FROM bbs_users b WHERE b.username = deleteUser; 

-- Just for test purposes, return INCORRECT id, but the CORRECT username  
SELECT b.id, b.username FROM bbs_users b WHERE b.username = 'anonymous';
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem, and you taught my something new.

Answer (score 0):

have you tryed repeat the sentence "FETCH cur1 INTO keepUser, deleteUser, id" after end if and before end loop...

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work any better.  Have cleaned up the locations where you're effectively doing the same query multiple times.  Sorry if I've misunderstood the problem - but if I've understood correctly then the query below should operate a bit more efficiently.  Also removes all ambiguous field names.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE catchUpBbs_Users()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE oldID INT;
    DECLARE newID INT;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT b.id 
        FROM users u 
        RIGHT JOIN bbs_users b 
        ON u.username = b.username 
        WHERE u.username IS NULL;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;     

    // Get the new id
    SELECT id INTO newID FROM bbs_users WHERE username = 'anonymous';

    OPEN cur1;
        allusers: LOOP 
            FETCH cur1 INTO oldID;  // b.id

            IF done THEN 
                LEAVE allusers; 
            END IF;

            IF deleteUser != 'anonymous' THEN 

                -- Just for test purposes, returns correct id and username 
                SELECT id, username FROM bbs_users WHERE id = oldID; 

                -- Just for test purposes, return INCORRECT id, but the CORRECT username  
                SELECT id, username FROM bbs_users WHERE id = newID; 

                UPDATE bbs_posts SET user_id = newID WHERE user_id = oldID;

                -- delete the user from the bbs_users table
                DELETE FROM bbs_users WHERE id = oldID;

            END IF;
        END LOOP allusers;
    CLOSE cur1;
END;

$$
DELIMITER ;
```